# Back transforming reciprocal transformation for difference between means

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spss, data-transformation, back-transformation

Say I have the  following datasets which concern normalised masses like this:

**Set 1:**
3.08,
2.79,
3.62,
2.62,
2.85,
2.45,
2.80,
2.62

**Set 2:**
3.25,
3.14,
3.30,
3.13,
3.19,
3.17,
3.35,
3.35,
3.82,
3.13

Now sample set 2 violates the assumption of normality, so I reciprocally transformed it (it looked like it couldn't be resolved by log transformation, the Q-Q plots were almost vertical)

and here is the transformed dataset:

**RecSet 1:** 
.32,
.36,
.28,
.38,
.35,
.41,
.36,
.38

**RecSet 2:**
.31,
.32,
.30,
.32,
.31,
.32,
.30,
.30,
.26,
.32

Now when I perform descriptive statistics in SPSS, I get the averages like this:

**Set 1:** 2.853

**Set 2:** 3.281

**RecSet 1:** 0.354

**RecSet 2:** 0.305

All's fair. I perform a one way ANOVA now (data contains multiple sets, have only shown 2 for example), I get a mean difference between RecSet1 and RecSet2 (0.049), Standard error (0.015) and CI [0.018,0.078] of the transformed dataset. How do I back transform these?

I can not just take 1/Mean difference = 1/0.049 because the resultinng value (somewhere in the 20's) does not make sense. What am I doing wrong?

Do note that the results can not be explained by reciprocals (1/mass doesn't mean anything biologically in this scenario).

Comment: Set 2 does not look all that non-normal: there are so few data that it plausibly could be a sample from a normal distribution.  In such cases it may be going too far to apply such a strong nonlinear transform (whose Box-Cox parameter is influenced entirely by a single value of 3.82). Since you're performing ANOVA, it doesn't seem to be relevant that this dataset is non-normal in the first place: ANOVA does not require normality. In fact, when the alternate hypothesis is true, ANOVA is tantamount to an *explicitly* non-normal model. Why, then, are you doing this?

Comment: @whuber apologies, should have been more explicit. I was worried about normality because the multiple comparisons after an ANOVA follow a principle of a t test which requires normality? Or am I wrong in assuming that pairwise comparisons do not require normality when done after an ANOVA? On the same note, should I prefer to perform log transformations instead?

Comment: The t-test requires normality of the *underlying distribution* of the *residuals*.  It does not require the residuals themselves to be normal (they can't be--they form a discrete distribution) and it does not require the actual data to be normal.  With such small datasets it will be difficult to detect departures from normality that could affect the t-test, so you are somewhat at the mercy of your assumptions regardless of what you do.

Comment: @whuber Many thanks for your input mate. I went back and checked the papers in my field, and the usual procedure is apparently transformation when a dataset fails to test for normality (KS or Shapiro-Wilks). Apologies, I am afraid I have to stick to that, since my data does fail both tests.

Comment: Sometimes it's tough to do the right thing when everybody appears to be making the same mistake. It could come down to having a rejected paper with a good analysis against having an accepted paper with a poor (or even wrong) analysis.  In some fields, the first people to recognize that something like that was going on, and showed the rest of their field a better way, were acclaimed as innovators and pioneers.  I won't inquire what your field is.

Comment: @whuber publication pressure does tend to lead to bad stats :(

Comment: @whuber had a discussion with my Prof. and he asked me to do the right stats, so I'll not transform the data as you suggested. Cheers for that mate. Out of curiosity, ignoring the data for now, I am curious as to know what is the answer to this question on academic grounds ?

Comment: What do you mean by "on academic grounds"?  Are you saying, "let's ignore whether or not analyzing the reciprocals is appropriate; assuming it is, how could one re-express ANOVA results based on reciprocals in terms of the original units of measurement?"

Comment: @whuber Yeah pretty much. Usually I just find on the net to take the reciprocal of the reciprocal transformed data to get our original scale back..does this hold true for the SD/SEM and CI as well  ?

Comment: You can't just take reciprocals to obtain SDs etc. It's worse than that: the assumption of normal reciprocal data implies [the original data don't even have a finite standard deviation!](http://tinyurl.com/pmhrmr5) Careful analysis and interpretation are needed in order to make sense of this.   Many people opt to use non-parametric versions of ANOVA when faced with such a situation. Those can be excellent choices--but they are lacking in power for small datasets. That's the tradeoff with all small datasets: if the results aren't obvious, then the conclusions are sensitive to the assumptions.

Comment: @whuber would you mind posting your comments as an answer so I can accept the same and mark the question answered ?

Comment: (1) What type of data is this? Is there an a-priori model we can expect and use that? If 'everybody' uses reciprocals, then might we conclude, a-priori, this is the "best" analysis? (2) What do you want to proof? Why go trough this (useless) trouble with underlying (normal) distribution models? Obviously set 1 has smaller values than set 2, except the 3.62 value. Point. In many fields the residuals are in practice rarely Gaussian distributed anyway (the same true for the reciprocals). This perfect Platonic world is mostly a thing for the early statistics gurus (nearly all bio-statisticians)